# The Arabic typing on my app is showing like binary code

Tags: mysql, gluon-mobile, javafxports

[image]

My app javafx ports after debugger on mobile android  the Arabic text is coming like if I choices from combo box or write the text on text field

But when I run it on my desktop is working very well and inserted very well  and retrieve very well on combo box

And by English retrieve and inserting there is no any problem just by Arabic

The data base setting is utf8 C_GENERAL_IC AND EVERTHING IS OK 
So what is the issue is look like this?

[image]

After i print the system.out.print 
dear @Jose check the fonts

```
AGA Rasheeq V.2 ???? Aayat Quraan 2 Aldhabi Andalus Arabic Typesetting Arial 
Arial Black Calibri Calibri Light Cambria Cambria Math Candara Comic Sans MS 
Consolas Constantia Corbel Courier New Digital-7 Digital-7 Italic Digital-7 
Mono Ebrima Franklin Gothic Medium Gabriola Gadugi Georgia HoloLens MDL2 
Assets Impact Ink Free Javanese Text Leelawadee UI Leelawadee UI Semilight 
Lucida Bright Lucida Console Lucida Sans Lucida Sans Typewriter Lucida Sans 
Unicode MS Gothic MS PGothic MS UI Gothic MV Boli Malgun Gothic Malgun 
Gothic Semilight Marlett Microsoft Himalaya Microsoft JhengHei Microsoft 
JhengHei Light Microsoft JhengHei UI Microsoft JhengHei UI Light Microsoft 
New Tai Lue Microsoft PhagsPa Microsoft Sans Serif Microsoft Tai Le 
Microsoft Uighur Microsoft YaHei Microsoft YaHei Light Microsoft YaHei UI 
Microsoft YaHei UI Light Microsoft Yi Baiti MingLiU-ExtB MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB 
Mohammad Rasool Allah Mongolian Baiti Monospaced Mukadimah Myanmar Text 
NSimSun Nirmala UI Nirmala UI Semilight PMingLiU-ExtB Palatino Linotype 
Sakkal Majalla SansSerif Segoe MDL2 Assets Segoe Print Segoe Script Segoe UI 
Segoe UI Black Segoe UI Emoji Segoe UI Historic Segoe UI Light Segoe UI 
Semibold Segoe UI Semilight Segoe UI Symbol Serif SimSun SimSun-ExtB 
Simplified Arabic Simplified Arabic Fixed Sitka Banner Sitka Display Sitka 
Heading Sitka Small Sitka Subheading Sitka Text Sylfaen Symbol System Tahoma 
TeamViewer8 Times New Roman Traditional Arabic Trebuchet MS Urdu Typesetting 
Verdana Webdings Wingdings Yu Gothic Yu Gothic Light Yu Gothic Medium Yu 
Gothic UI Yu Gothic UI Light Yu Gothic UI Semibold Yu Gothic UI Semilight 
ae_Cortoba
```

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178068/use-gluon-plugins-deploy-an-android-apk-then-all-of-the-chinese-charactor-is-not). While it is not a fix, you could make a quick test retrieving and testing the fonts in your system with `Font.getFamilies() `, and checking which font might work for you.

Comment: Dear @JoséPereda i do font.getfamilies() in system print and i change the font type still i'm facing the same issue check the pic console is printing all the fonts

Comment: One easy way to test it: Create a view with just a ListView. Set the items with `listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFamilies()));`, and add a cell factory, with a Label. In the `updateItem` method, set the font `label.setFont(Font.font(item, 20));` and the text `label.setText(item);`. Deploy to mobile, and scroll over all the items, see if any font renders Arabic characters properly.

Comment: dear @JoséPereda check i edit my question there is alot of fonts

Comment: The idea is that you actually try out all of those fonts on a label that you can render on your app (this is why using a list view is handy, because you can apply all of them at once), then find out which of those fonts renders correctly.

Comment: oh ok Dear @JoséPereda i understand now from the scene builder or from the css i will choose which of the fonts is allow to typing Arabic on android i'll try then i'll give you feed back

Comment: See my comment, this is not done with SB/CSS. Create or reuse a view in your app, add a ListView, and add an item for every font. Set a label on that item with that font. Then deploy your app to mobile, and go to that view. Then you can be sure of which fonts are rendered or not.

Comment: can you please give code for check by list view  ? because i try from my side is give me the fonts name i need to try to write somthing like this "بسم الله " and i need to check in all fonts and show the result on conloso or listview

Comment: dear @JoséPereda i try every fonts is not support and i try another way to  call the fonts from resource file `customername.setFont(Font.loadFont("file:resources/Fonts/DroidKufi-Bold.ttf", 10));`  also the same thing is not supporting