Gluon Javafx textfield cannot input Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters on IOS
I am developing an iOS application using Gluon Mobile but have encountered a problem. When a TextField gains focus, the keyboard pops up, but this keyboard is different from the one configured in the iOS operating system. I have configured input methods for Chinese, Japanese Kana, Korean, French, etc., but in the app's keyboard, I cannot find the Chinese or Korean input methods when switching input methods. The Japanese Kana input method is available, but I cannot enter any Japanese characters into the TextField. How can I solve this problem?
I have searched through all the questions on StackOverflow but still have not found an answer. I am looking forward to a solution as soon as possible.
Chinese / Korean input methods should be supported.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44520477/3956070

The two issues are different. That is the problem of Chinese display, which can be solved by setting the font. This problem is that you can not enter Chinese, the pop-up keyboard can not choose the Chinese input method.
